# C++ application crashes in a 64 bit version of windows but works fine on 32 bit windows

Tags: c++, .net, com

So I have a Visual C++ application, in my code I use the CoCreateInstance function which is used to create a COM object and get an interface from the object:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615(v=vs.85).aspx

This function:

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CppCmnBL, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
         IID_ICppCmnBL, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pBL));
```

Works fine on a 32 bit version of windows but fails on a 64 bit version of windows.

I've looked everywhre, it seems there are issues registering 32 bit objects on a 64 bit system.

Related issues:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3841717c-a736-46d0-b214-0b047efcd16c/32-bit-app-cocreateinstance-failed-on-64-bit-windows-with-error-0x80090006-invalid-signature?forum=vclanguage

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?400956-32-bit-app-CoCreateInstance-fails-on-64-bit

The exception I get is: System.AccessViolationException

Comment: 32 bit programs can not load 64 bit DLLs and vice versa, which for COM means in-process servers must match the bitness of the host process. You could try creating it as an out-of-process server if the object supports it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Ok let me further explain, my application is a 32 Bit Application, now I'm trying to run it on a 64-bit Windows, it runs fine except  that in some functionality in the application I have to use the CoCreateInstance function but it now fails.

Comment: @JonathanPotter My Application is running as a 32 bit process on a 64 bit windows environment

Comment: Ok, so do you have a 32 bit version of the COM DLL registered correctly?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm not trying to load a 64 bit dll

Comment: @JonathanPotter yes I have a 32 bit version of the COM DLL but I'm not srue if it's registered correctly, all I know is that it works fine on 32 bit windows.

Comment: @JonathanPotter The executable creating COM obj is also 32 bit.

Only thing is that it works fine when I run it on 32 bit windows.

But it fails on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: Does this work on **every** 32-bit Windows system, or just one which happens also to have your development tools installed?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes it works on every 32-bit windows system, it only fails on 64-bit windows.

Comment: How many 64-bit Windows systems have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Please do this:

1. Clarify the #/binaries involved.

I assumed you had one .exe (the one calling  CoCreateInstance()), and one .dll (the Com/ActiveX object you're trying to instantiate).  Is this correct?

2. Please run `dumpbin /all` on your binaries and post the results.

Please run dumpbin on *all* relevant binaries; *especially* the COM/ActiveX class.

A Win32 .dll should like something like this:

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               3 number of sections
        5355B2AD time date stamp Mon Apr 21 17:07:09 2014
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
            2102 characteristics
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine
                   DLL

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
```

3. Please clarify which binaries you've attempted to rebuild with your
   MSVS 6 compiler.

MSVS 6 won't work with .Net; MSVS 6 won't build C++11 code ... but it should be fine if all you're trying to do is get a legacy app working.  Again, I'm assuming there's only one .exe, and one .dll in the mix.

I'm assuming the .exe can be compiled as a 32-bit Win32 .exe (*not* a .Net .exe), and the .dll is a Win32, COM/ActiveX class. Both should have "PE32" headers in dumpbin. Please advise if otherwise.

I'm assuming you have control over, and can rebuild and debug, *ALL* of the relevant source code for this app.  Please advise if otherwise.

4. You should be able to register a COM/ActiveX .dll with regsvr32.

If you can't, that's probably an indicator that "something is wrong", and I'd focus your troubleshooting efforts there.

I hope that helps!

Comment: how do I run dumpobj /all ?

Comment: I get the following error when trying to run regsvr32 on my DLL: "The module "MODULE_NAME.dll" was loaded ut the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found . make sure that "MODULE_NAME.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Comment: He probably means dumpbin.  I have never heard of dumpobj and it fails for me from a standard command line with Visual Studio paths added.

Comment: Sorry about that - brain fart :(.  Yes, `dumpbin /all`. The fact that you can't run `regsvr32` is probably a Bad Sign.  Please a) run dumbin on all your binaries, b) specify your compiler, compiler version, and exactly which binaries you are/are not rebuilding.  I'm also curious how you determined `CoCreateInstance()` is the line causing the access violation.

Comment: @paulsm4 dumpbin /all returns nothing. The compiler is visual c++ 6.0 (32 bit). If I use the CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER flag in the CoCreateInstance function I get an AccessViolationException and the entire application crashes, if I use the CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER flag in CoCreaetInstance the application doesn't crash but I get a vague error stating "Error saving status writer object.", NOTE: This website has more information on these flags: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693716(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: "dumpbin/all" can't return "nothing". At a *minimum*, it'll say something like `d:\temp\tmp.txt : warning LNK4048: Invalid format file; ignored`.  But it *should* tell you lots of things: including whether it's x86, whether it's 32-bit, and whether it's `PE32` object format.  Q: Are you rebuilding the .dll in question with your (very old, circa 2000) MSVS 6 compiler?  Q: CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER is what you want, isn't it?  How did it "used to work"?

Comment: PS: `System.AccessViolationException` implies a .Net .exe.  You couldn't possibly be building a .Net exe with MSVS 6, could you?

Comment: @paulsm4 That Visual C++ DLL runs on a .NET application so I assume that's why it shows that exception. CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER is what was originally used, I just tried different flags to see if it would do something different. CoCreateInstance with the CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER works fine on a Windows 2003 Server 32-Bit , recently they installed this application on a Windows 2012 Server 64-Bit and that's where this function crashes. The application was compiled as a 32-bit application running on the 64bit win 2012 server

Comment: @Eric - please clarify if your exe app is .NET or VC++. If it is .NET and built with the Any CPU configuration, and it is running on x64 Windows, then it is a 64-bit app and your VC++ code also needs to be 64-bit.

Comment: @DavidChing The .NET app was built using x86

Comment: @JonathanPotter It's not my choice, I'm maintaining legacy code.

Comment: @EricBergman: It doesn't matter if it was built on an x86 machine, it matters what the compile options were.  Please add all the relevant information to your question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes that's what I meant, it was built with x86 compile options.

Comment: @EricBergman: make sure you are running the 32-bit regsvr32, e.g. `c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe`.  Until the COM control is successfully registered (no "DllRegisterServer not found" error), your code will not work (although the Access Denied exception is puzzling).

Comment: @Eric Bergman: please update your post with answers to all four of my questions above.  In particular, please clarify exactly how many "binaries" are involved and their platform (one .Net .exe + one COM/ActiveX .dll?)  Please make sure you can successfully run `dumpbin /all` and `regsvr32`.  And finally, please get the .exe source and step into the `CoCreateInstance()` call with the MSVS debugger.  It's entirely possible that one or more of the input arguments are wrong/corrupt.  Please add the results to your post.